# Avoid StacklessClosedChannelException

Tags: exception, netty

I was looking for a way to avoid StacklessClosedChannelException, but I didn't find anything. I suppose it's not safe and it shouldn't happen, how to avoid it?

Comment: please show the full stack trace

Comment: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.

 io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException

  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(Object, ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source)

Comment: This means the channel was closed while there were still writes in process. This can be because of the remote peer closed the channel or you did.

Comment: That's understandable, but how to avoid this exception?

Comment: You basically can't if its triggered by the remote peer. If its triggered by yourself you need to ensure all writes happen before you actually close the channel.

Comment: How to ensure all writes happen? Or do I need just to make sure channel is opened before writing?

Comment: @andreasdc did you find any solution to this problem . As I also experience the same.

Comment: I didn't find good solution to that.

Comment: My logs are really full of it, how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such exceptions, you should check whether the channel is active or at least open. There is a boolean verification that can achieve that. Here's the Kotlin version:

```kotlin
    val f: ChannelFuture = bootstrap.connect(HOST, PORT).sync()
    val channel = f.channel()

    if (channel?.isActive == true) {
        val f: ChannelFuture? = channel?.writeAndFlush(msg)?.sync()
    else {
        //Channel not even open and therefore it's not writable
    }
```

There is also a `ìsWritable` boolean but I did not test it sufficiently.